# Get input from a jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How would I get user input from a jtextfield in my GUI? Would I use java.util.Scanner or another class?

```
JTextField a = new JTextField("Input Here")
//Put calculation formula here
```

Comment: `.getText`  Please read the documentation for JTextField...

Comment: You will want to read the documentation *before* coming here. That's what it's for.

Comment: [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GUI is an event driven environment. You will need to listen to the events that the component is producing.

For example, `JTextField` raises `ActionEvent`s (amongst others) which tells you that the user has (on most systems) pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Start by taking a look at [How to use Textfields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

When your ready, you can use `getText` to get the String value that the user entered...